# How to select MySQL rows order by highest values from any column?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table of 2000 columns and 120000 rows (numerical values). I wanna select the some rows based on highest value from all 2000 columns.

```
select * from table where column1='x' ORDER BY all_columns DESC;
```

Basically I wanna order multiple columns based on highest value of any column not one-by-one.

Comment: 2000 column?!! That is unusual.

Comment: What do you mean "highest value from all 2000 columns"?

Comment: If they are not all the same datatype that would not work

Comment: I wanna sort rows based on highest value from all the columns not from any specific column.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may want this:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by greatest(col1, col2, col3, . . . ) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a column number in order by, so you should be able to do something like:

```
select * from table 
where column1='x' 
ORDER BY 1 DESC,2 DESC,3 DESC,4 DESC ..... 1999 DESC,2000 DESC;
```

I don't think there is a shorter way, but using the right equipment, it should be doable. I am very curious about your usecase, though. This is an extreme number of columns, and most certainly extreme to sort by all of them.